Asp.net. Пропадают куки при редиректе
Попал на легаси-проект mvc, написанный на .net 6. Выполняем доработки  - авторизация через сервис Keycloak. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Перед редиректом пользователя на форму keycloak сохраняю в куке гуид (что бы потом сверить его с тем, что вернёт keycloak)
var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
    key, 
    state, 
    new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true });
дальше логика с редиректом

Если пользователь не авторизован и приходится заполнять форму, то при редитекте обратно в проект кука пропадает. А вот если пользователь уже авторизаван (т.е. редиректит сразу обратно, без необходимости что-то вводить) кука сохраняется.
var cookieState = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?
    .Request.Cookies[key];
дальше логика с проверкой

Подскажите, кто сталкивался, как решили?
